# Create pinnable shortcut on desktop C# - .website extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Trying to create a .website shortcut (pinnable shortcut) on the desktop via a button click (C#).

I have the existing code (that works - but the browser opens and *immediately* closes)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ShortcutUpdater
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

    private void urlShortcutToDesktop(string linkName, string linkUrl)
    {
        string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + linkName + ".website"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
            writer.WriteLine("URL=" + linkUrl);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }


        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string linkName = "My Site";
            string linkUrl = "https://Asite.org";
            urlShortcutToDesktop(linkName, linkUrl);
        }
```

The file created looks like this when opened in Notepad:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://Asite.org
```

If I create a pinnable shortcut by dragging the icon to my desktop from the browser and then open it with Notepad, it looks like this (and is what I want to achieve so it won't just open then close the browser):

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop4=31,asite.org
Prop3=19,11
[{A7AF692E-098D-4C08-A225-D433CA835ED0}]
Prop5=3,0
Prop9=19,0
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://asite.org/
IDList=
IconFile=https://asite.org/favicon.ico
IconIndex=1
[{9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}]
Prop5=8,Microsoft.Website.50DFA192.38C0BBDC
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: May not be your code that is causing this to happen. It may be a Windows security prohibiting application to access certain threads or functionality on your computer (i.e internet)

Comment: So I should not be trying to recreate the "Prop4=blah blah, Prop2=blah blah" stuff?

I am not sure what those are - or how to access/create them.

Comment: Have you tried to right click the pinnable shortcut and seen the access properties it has? Maybe needs admin?

Comment: When I click on the properties of each - they are utterly identical in the 'General tab', the 'Security Tab', and the 'Details Tab'. Quite literally the only difference is all those lines that say "Prop4=blahblah"

Comment: I created multiple shortcuts and the Prop numbers are always the same but the long strings in brackets change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact an official programming interface to create [internet shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784.aspx). Unfortunately, the interfaces aren't readily available to .NET programs, and there is no type library either for use with [Tlbimp.exe (Type Library Importer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx). That leaves only two options: Trying to replicate the interface definitions in C#, or using a native implementation.

I'll propose going with a native implementation, specifically, a C++/CLI *Class Library*, that can be immediately consumed<sup>1</sup> by .NET code. The implementation consists of 2 types: A native implementation class (`InternetShortcutImpl`) and a proxy to expose the functionality to managed code, implemented as a ref class (`InternetShortcut`). Both classes can be placed in the same file.

This is the implementation of the native access class:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <comip.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <IntShCut.h>
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF( IUniformResourceLocatorW, __uuidof( IUniformResourceLocatorW ) );
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF( IPersistFile, __uuidof( IPersistFile ) );
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF( IShellLinkW, __uuidof( IShellLinkW ) );
class InternetShortcutImpl
{
public:
    InternetShortcutImpl()
    {
        HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance( CLSID_InternetShortcut, nullptr,
                                         CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                         IID_IUniformResourceLocatorW,
                                         (void**)&m_spURL );
        if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
            throw gcnew ExternalException( nullptr, hr );
        }
    }

    void SetURL( const std::wstring& url ) {
        HRESULT hr = m_spURL->SetURL( url.c_str(), 0x0 );
        if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
            throw gcnew ExternalException( nullptr, hr );
        }
    }

    void SetIconLocation( const std::wstring& iconpath, int index ) {
        IShellLinkWPtr spLink;
        HRESULT hr = m_spURL->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &spLink ) );
        if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
            hr = spLink->SetIconLocation( iconpath.c_str(), index );
        }
        if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
            throw gcnew ExternalException( nullptr, hr );
        }
    }

    void Save( const std::wstring& pathname, bool remember ) {
        IPersistFilePtr spFile;
        HRESULT hr = m_spURL->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &spFile ) );
        if SUCCEEDED( hr ) {
            hr = spFile->Save( pathname.c_str(), remember ? TRUE : FALSE );
        }
        if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
            throw gcnew ExternalException( nullptr, hr );
        }
    }
private:
    IUniformResourceLocatorWPtr m_spURL;
};
```

And this is the proxy class, that essentially only forwards calls from .NET to the native class, which it contains as a member:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

namespace ShortcutInteropLib {
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4461)  // "this class has a finalizer but no destructor"
    public ref class InternetShortcut
    {
    public:
        InternetShortcut() {
            m_pImpl = new InternetShortcutImpl();
        }

        void SetURL( String^ url ) {
            m_pImpl->SetURL( msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>( url ) );
        }

        void SetIconLocation( String^ iconpath, int index ) {
            m_pImpl->SetIconLocation( msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>( iconpath ),
                                      index );
        }

        void Save( String^ pathname, bool remember ) {
            m_pImpl->Save( msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>( pathname ),
                           remember );
        }

        !InternetShortcut() {
            delete m_pImpl;
        }

    private:
        InternetShortcutImpl* m_pImpl;
    };
#pragma warning(pop)
}
```

This forms the entire library, which can be referenced from a .NET assembly. The calling code is trivially easy:

```cs
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var shortcut = new InternetShortcut();
        shortcut.SetURL(@"http://www.example.com");
        //shortcut.SetIconLocation(@"http://www.example.com/favicon", 1);
        shortcut.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
                      + @"\MyShortCut.url", false);
    }
}
```

This creates a shortcut to http://www.example.com on the desktop. Note that while I implemented a `SetIconLocation`, I don't know how to use it with URLs. While the icon index is properly stored in the resulting *MyShortCut.url* file, the path is interpreted as a path into the local filesystem<sup>2</sup>.

The code produces the following internet shortcut on my system:

> ```
> [{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
> Prop3=19,2
> [InternetShortcut]
> IDList=
> URL=http://www.example.com/
> ```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Since a C++/CLI class library contains native code, you'll have to select a target architecture. Client code must reference the appropriate assembly.*

<sup>2</sup> *I don't know if there is a special syntax that allows to pass a URL, and not have the system interpret the argument as a local filesystem path. If anyone knows, I would be happy to hear about it.*